# Unity3D object doesn't move on rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my object rotate using Raycast and move in that direction. However when my object rotates, it does not move into the new direction. Instead it just moves in the same direction it has been moving. Any idea why it doesn't change direction?
    public class ControlCar : MonoBehaviour {

```
CharacterController controller;
public int Speed;
public int Raydir;
public int RotateSpeed;
public int FrontRay;
public int RayDist;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

    RayDist = 4;
    FrontRay = 3;
    RotateSpeed = 10;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Move ();
    HandleRay ();

}

void Move(){
        transform.position += Vector3.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime;

    }

void HandleRay(){
    //Front Ray
    Vector3 Front = transform.TransformDirection(0,0,1) * FrontRay;
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, Front, 10)) {
        Debug.Log ("Front hit!");
            }

    //Front right
    Vector3 FrontR = transform.TransformDirection(1,0,1) * RayDist;
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, FrontR, 10)) {
        Debug.Log ("Right hit!");
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,-RotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime,0));

    }

    //Front Left
    Vector3 FrontL = transform.TransformDirection(-1,0,1) * RayDist;
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, FrontL, 10)) {
        Debug.Log ("Left hit!");
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,RotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime,0));
    }




    //DebugRay
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, FrontL, Color.green);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, FrontR, Color.red);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Front, Color.blue);
    }
}
```

My entire project can be seen here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d7yxhjg5humw3vo/AAD5IfBW8slRw8-AT072DsWea?dl=0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the RotateSpeed and FrontRay set to?

Comment: FrontRay = 3;
  RotateSpeed = 10;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector3.forward always returns the equivalent of: new Vector3(0, 0, 1). It doesn't actually relate to the rotation of the transform in anyway unfortunately.

Vector3.forward is always north, Vector3.back is always south, Vector3.right is always east, Vector3.left is always west, Vector3.up is always up, Vector3.down is always down, and Vector3.one is right, up, and forward in one call. Vector3.zero is essentially: new Vector3(0, 0, 0).

Comment: Note that `transform` also has similarly named properties which to relate the local directions to global space

Comment: transform.position += transform.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime;

This works now, thanks for your help!

Comment: I didn't actually even know about the transform.forward property, so this is news to me. Cheers Aravol.

Answer (score 0):

try swapping these two around.

```
  void Update () 
  {
       HandleRay ();
       Move ();
  }
```

Then the move should be facing the correct direction when you apply forward.